# Что нужно прописать в стилистике выпадающего меню, чтобы при наведении на него оно не пропадало?

Tags: javascript, css, меню

Проблема в том, что при наведении меню выпадает, но как только переводишь курсор вниз - оно тут же исчезает. В honey прописала display:block;, сначала все работало, теперь опять слетело, не пойму, в чем проблема

Comment: пример в студию ))

Comment: @АлександрСычёв, да на любом сайте, где попытались сделать меню из html-блоков, будут проблемы, например, при изменении масштаба в браузере. автору: не парьтесь вы. абсолютно надёжно эти фокусы ни у кого не получается реализовать.

Comment: нужно чтобы между меню и его ховер-тригером не было промежутка. если он нужен стилистически, заполните его прозрачным блоком. и само меню тоже должно быть для себя ховер-тригером(достаточно засунуть его в тригер)

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте этот фрагмент:

.menu-item:hover>.submenu { }

-должен работать